# Почему я не могу выйти из цикла, когда жму "Отменить"?

Tags: javascript

Почему не выходит из цикла, когда жмешь в окне prompt "Отменить". Цикл продолжает работать.

```
function getUserName() {

    let userName = prompt('Введите имя и фамилию нового пользователя: ');

    if (userName !== null) {

        let separatedName = splitString(userName, ' ');
        let firstName = separatedName[0];
        let lastName = separatedName[1];

        let newUser = new User(firstName, lastName);
        newUser.add(newUser);

    }
    else {

        let print = new UserList();

        print.getAllUsers();
        return null;

    }

    while (userName !== null) {

        getUserName();

    }

}
```

Comment: А как ты проверил? Если ввести хотя бы одно значение, то потом нельзя выйти из цикла

Comment: Надо вызов функции заменить на goto start, тогда всё должно заработать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не всё

Comment: @Igor ага, недопроверил)

Comment: Подумайте над тем, сколько экземпляров функции getUserName у вас запущено. И, соответственно, сколько у вас разных локальных переменных userName.

Answer (score 4):

А как локальная переменная `userName` станет `null` (чтобы цикл остановился) после вызова `getUserName` внутри `while`? Подумайте.